# cmake variable that is not declared before

Tags: cmake, compilation

I found the following cmake script located on a root [directory](https://github.com/yijiangh/ikfast_pybind/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt).

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
project(ikfast_pybind)

set(IKFAST_PYBIND_ROOT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}")
set(IKFAST_PYBIND_SOURCE_DIR "${IKFAST_PYBIND_ROOT}/src")
```

Something made me confused is variable `IKFAST_PYBIND_ROOT`. I guessed from its name that this variable is auto-generated when `project(ikfast_pybind)` is called. However, when I look at the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/project.html) of `project()`, variables `<PROJECT-NAME>_SOURCE_DIR` and `<PROJECT-NAME>_BINARY_DIR` are mentioned as auto-generated ones, but no explanation is found about `<PROJECT-NAME>_ROOT`.

It would be helpful someone explains how this variable is generated.

Comment: "Something made me confused is variable `IKFAST_PYBIND_ROOT`." - This is just a *user-defined* variable which has no special meaning for CMake. Following line defines another variable `IKFAST_PYBIND_SOURCE_DIR` which is also *user-defined* one. CMake generates the variable `ikfast_pybind_SOURCE_DIR` (substitution `<PROJECT-NAME>` is **case-sensitive**).

Comment: Thank you @Tsyvarev. Then, could you tell me where `IKFAST_PYBIND_ROOT` is declared? This variable does not show up anywhere in the script...

Comment: "where IKFAST_PYBIND_ROOT is declared?" - Eh? The command [set](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/set.html) declares the variable.

Comment: ah, sorry I found it...